# How to revert direction for last parameter shortcut?

Tags: bash, command-history

I can append a last used parameter via the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> yet sometimes, I type too fast and miss my actual target. If I wanted to go back one instance, is there a way to do it?

I unsuccessfully tried to modify it via <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.

How to revert direction of the last parameter shortcut?

Comment: I normally swear and try again :)

Comment: @Bernhard I've just been there. Again. Hence the question ;)

Comment: Looks like this has been asked before on [superuser: How can you reverse the direction of alt-period in Bash?](http://superuser.com/questions/593857/how-can-you-reverse-the-direction-of-alt-period-in-bash)

Comment: Define "target" and "instance" please.

Comment: @glennjackman Typing alt. four times, while you needed three.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like most commands, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> takes a [numeric argument](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Readline-Arguments). Passing an argument of -1 reverses the direction. Hence:

> <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>
>   <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>
>   <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>
>   Oops, overshot!
>   <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>